# Java - try & catch in calling methods

Tags: java

I have a basic question in Java:

I have two methods: `functionA` & `functionB`. `functionA` calls `functionB`, and `functionB` rise an exception. The call to `functionB` is in try scope of `functionA`.

Now I also want that `functionA` will go to it catch scope.

There is any way to do that?

Comment: Your question is unclear. What does "I also want that functionA will go to it catch scope"?

Comment: functionA call functionB. Now, functionB rise an exception. So functionB go to it catch scope. I also want that functionA will go to it catch scope, when it return from the functionB calling.

Comment: Sorry, that doesn't help - it's neither good English nor does it make any technical sense. Please show an example *in code* of what you've tried, and what you want to happen.

Comment: rethrow it in B's catch Block and declare `throws` clause for functionB then it will go to A's catch Block. But its not clear what you exactly want to achieve

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If an exception is thrown in `methodB` and you catch it, one way to propagate it to `methodA` is to rethrow it:

```
void methodB() throws SomeException {
    try {
        //Something that can throw SomeException
    } catch (SomeException e) {
        //rethrow e
        throw e;
    }
}

void methodA() {
    try {
        methodB();
    } catch (SomeException e) {
        //this block will run if methodB throws SomeException
    }
}
```

But if you need that, you probably should not catch the exception in `methodB` at all and just let it propagate automatically to `methodA`:

```
void methodB() throws SomeException {
    //Something that can throw SomeException: don't catch it
}

void methodA() {
    try {
        methodB();
    } catch (SomeException e) {
        //this block will run if methodB throws SomeException
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Actually, that is how it works usually, provided that `functionB` doesn't catch the exception itself. Exceptions, when thrown, bubble up the call stack until a matching `catch` block is found.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is what you want

```
 void functionB() throws MyException {
 try{
 .....
}Catch(MyException e){
//do something here;
 throw e;
}
}

void functionA() {
try {
    functionB();
} catch (MYException e) {
    //do something else to A here
}
}
```